# Select 1 value from 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table of `teachers` with the following column

```
TID, Fname, Lname, Email, uname, pass, grade, subject, start time, end time
```

[image]

The problem is that I want to select those teachers who have the subject of science but here in my subject column there are two values like this:

```
-------------------
|     subject     |
-------------------
| maths, science  |
-------------------
```

How would i select only science from this column?

Comment: Is it `mysql` or `sql-server`? Please use only the tag that matches the product you are using.

Comment: The usual problem of this type of denormalized design with multiple entries in a single column is incorrect substring matches in the event of a course called `Biosciences`, you can stuff in false delimiters to deal with this but this table should be redesigned; it will be a nightmare to manage.

Comment: oops!!! sorry for that it is sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use like this

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [SUBJECT] IN ( 'Science');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a wildcard like this

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [Subject] LIKE '%Science%'
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 2):

> How would i select only science from this column?

Not sure what you actually mean by this but here goes

**Get all teachers who teach Science at all**

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Subject LIKE '%Science%'
```

**Get teachers who teach Science but don't show that they teach Math**

```
SELECT TID, Fname, Lname, 'Science'
FROM table
WHERE Subject LIKE '%Science%'
```

**Get all teachers who only teach Science**

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Subject = 'Science'
```

Use whichever you're looking for